# Is there any way to create a ECS load balancer without containers behind?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk, amazon-elb, aws-fargate

I'm using CDK to create a stack in AWS. What I need is an infrastructure *to be ready* to have future containers inside. A lambda behind an API Gateway will fire a Fargate task, creating this new container, as the user demands it, but I am not able to deploy it successfully because the load balancer needs to pass health checks and obviously no container is up at that moment. [Examples like this one](https://towardsthecloud.com/aws-cdk-alb-fargate-service) show how to bring up the LB with at least 1 container. Is it able to do what I am trying to do?

This is what I have at the moment:

```js
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import * as ecr from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ecr';
import * as ec2 from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2';
import * as ecs from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-ecs";
import * as lambda from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda";
import * as ecsPatterns from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-ecs-patterns";
import * as elb2 from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-elasticloadbalancingv2";
import * as path from 'path';
import * as assets from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-s3-assets';

export class MyStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const repository = new ecr.Repository(this, 'ecr-repository', {
      imageScanOnPush: true,
      removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
    });

    const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, 'public-vpc', {
      maxAzs: 3,
      subnetConfiguration: [
        {
          name: 'public-vpc',
          subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
        },
      ],
    });

    const cluster = new ecs.Cluster(this, 'ecs-cluster', {
      containerInsights: true,
      capacity: {
        instanceType: new ec2.InstanceType('t2.nano'),
        minCapacity: 0,
        maxCapacity: 10,
      },
      vpc: vpc
    });

    // This task will create the new container when the lambda runs it
    const task = new ecs.TaskDefinition(this, 'fargate-task', {
      compatibility: ecs.Compatibility.EC2_AND_FARGATE,
      cpu: '256',
      memoryMiB: '512',
    });
    task.addContainer('container-image', {
      image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromEcrRepository(repository, 'latest'),
      cpu: 1,
      memoryReservationMiB: 512,
      portMappings: [
        {
          containerPort: 8080,
          protocol: ecs.Protocol.TCP,
        },
      ],
    });

    // The load balancer over the cluster _should_ not expect any container to exist at this point (that's what I am trying to achieve) 
    const ecsLoadBalancer = new ecsPatterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedEc2Service(this, 'ecs-load-balancer', {
      cluster: cluster,
      taskDefinition: task,
      cpu: 256,
      memoryLimitMiB: 512,
      publicLoadBalancer: true,
      targetProtocol: elb2.ApplicationProtocol.HTTP,
      listenerPort: 8080,
    });

    const lambdaAsset = new assets.Asset(this, 'lambda-handler.zip', {
      path: path.join(__dirname, '../resources/lambda-handler.zip'),
    });

    const fn = new lambda.Function(this, 'lambda-handler', {
      allowPublicSubnet: true,
      handler: 'index.handler',
      code: lambda.Code.fromBucket(lambdaAsset.bucket, lambdaAsset.s3ObjectKey),  
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_16_X,
      environment: {
        TASK_DEFINITION_ARN: task.taskDefinitionArn,
        CLUSTER_ARN: cluster.clusterArn,
        SUBNET_ID: vpc.publicSubnets[0].subnetId,
        SECURITY_GROUP_ID: vpc.vpcDefaultSecurityGroup,
      },
      vpc,
    });
  }
}
```

This way, when I run `cdk deploy` it takes forever because it keeps waiting for health check to pass and no one is responding. If I add the following to the load balancer:

```js
    ecsLoadBalancer.targetddGroup.configureHealthCheck({
      enabled: false,
    });
```

It says that it is invalid for this instance type:

```
1:02:01 AM | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup  | ecsloadbalanc...erECSGroupE1CFCFA4
Resource handler returned message: "Health check enabled must be true for target groups with target type 'instance' (Service: ElasticLoadBalancingV2, Status C
ode: 400, Request ID: xxxxx)" (RequestToken: xxxxx, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

Also I've tried to add `desiredCount: 0` at the LB but CDK does not allow me even to `synth` it since minimum value is 1.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Why do you need a load balancer, you can run ECS tasks without an ALB.

Comment: Because the user will be interacting with the container directly, once it is up and running. Think in it as a "on demand" service.

Comment: You can interact with the container directly without a load balancer.